Does a strictly increasing subsequence of $\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ has the same sup?
My intuition tells me that a strictly increasing subsequence of $\{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in\mathbb{N} \}$ has $1$ as the supremum from Monontone Convergence Theorem and the fact that all subsequences of a convergent sequence converge to the same limit. Could it be otherwise?

Every strictly increasing subsequence must be finite.

@fleablood not sure I completely understood. Can you say more please?

To explain @fleablood's comment: if the first of your sequence is $1/4$, then second is at least $1/3$, the third is at least $1/2$ and the forth is at least $1$... The same holds with first term $1/n_0$: your sequence will be at most $n_0$ terms-long.

Depending on one's definition of "sequence" and "subsequence" (not clear if a "sequence" in OP's world is simply a set of numbers or if the purported "sequence" is introduced implicitly, via the function used to index a set of numbers), this "sequence" (and indeed many other "sequences") has no strictly increasing "subsequence." (Under a common definition of "subsequence," a function that picks out only finitely many indices of a given "sequence" is not yet a "subsequence" at all, and the proof just sketched in comments amounts to a proof that no strictly increasing "subsequence" exists)

Related to my last comment, and to understanding issues around the monotone convergence theorem, under common definitions of "sequence" and "subsequence," while it is true that every bounded sequence has a monotone subsequence, and while many bounded sequences have both increasing and decreasing subsequences, in general one may not be able to choose the "monotonicity type" of a subsequence of a given bounded sequence, and literally every subsequence of $n \mapsto 1/n$ is decreasing

Whatever the first term is, say $\frac 1k$ then there are only terms larger than $\frac 1k$ are $\frac 1m$ where $m < k$.  There are only $k-1$ such numbers and as your sequence is strictly increasing the terms must be distinct.  So there are only a finite number of terms.  In my book a sequence must have an infinite number of terms (otherwise it's just a finite list). But if not, we can have a finite sequence such as $\frac 1{27}, \frac 1{18}, frac 1{6}, \frac 1{2}$ and it just ends there.Is that "converging" to $\frac 12$?  I would say no, but if you are using different definitions... maybe.
